# Set animation position

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm using Godot 4 beta. I want to skip to a specific frame in an `AnimationPlayer`, but I'm getting:

> Invalid set index 'current_animation_position' (on base: 'AnimationPlayer') with value of type 'float'.

Here's the related documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-property-current-animation-position

I currently have one `AnimationPlayer` in my scene, named `'animation'`, with an animation named `'Animation'` with *"Autoplay on Load"*. The animation `'Animation'` has a length of 4.x seconds.

[image: Editor (1)]

Here's my code attached to the scene:

```
func _process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_released("skip_intro"):
        if animation_player.current_animation_position < 1.3:
            animation_player.current_animation_position = 1.3
        else:
            skip_intro()
```

#### Update (2)

I know I can use `animation_player.advance()`, but it adds to the relative time. I'm looking for a way to go to a fixed frame, not a relative frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation you linked [`current_animation_position`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-property-current-animation-position) only has a getter. It is a read-only property.

If you want to go to an specific time you can use the [`seek`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-method-seek) method.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use `play()` before `advance()` to go to an absolute frame. But I'd appreciate any other way to do it inliner.

```
animation_player.play("Animation")
animation_player.advance(1.3)
```

IMO it should be allowed to rewrite the `current_animation_position` property.